# Cruisecontrol.net Build Number on a Force Build

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to have ccnet don't increment the build number if the build is actually a forcebuild?????????? In better words, Is it possible to have cruisecontrol keep it's label number if it is rcovering from an exception(sourcecontrol exception)??? Basically if the forcebuild is happening to recover from an exception, I don't want my build number to change.

Answer (score 3):

It depends - why are you forcing the build?

If you need some kind of [interval trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Interval+Trigger), then just set it up and don't use forced build.

If you are forcing the build because the previous one has failed, then just set [incrementOnFailure](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Default+Labeller) to false (which is the default).

If you are using [Assembly Version Labeller](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Assembly+Version+Labeller) then you can explicitly set build revision - unfortunately this is not possible with other labellers.

Comment: I guess the second case is my problem, but even in that case cruisecontrol will still increment the label when build is succesful after an exception(I don't want this to happen).